# Efficient way to calculate matrix cell distance from arbitrary coordinate in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am looking for an efficient numpy solution to the following problem:

I have a N by N numpy matrix. Given an arbitrary i,j coordinate (can be decimal) of the matrix and an arbitrary range, I need to calculate the value of each cell of the matrix divided by its euclidian distance to the coordinate within the range specified.

In case that was not clear. Given coordinate (5.2, 5.5) and a range of 1. I need to take all 8 neighbors of cell (5,5) and the cell itself and divide those cell values by their distance to (5.2, 5.5).

Below is a simple really slow version of the code.

```
PROXIMITY_RANGE = 1
x = 5.2
y = 5.5
min_x = int(max(int(x) - PROXIMITY_RANGE, 0))
max_x = int(min(int(x) + PROXIMITY_RANGE, IMAGE_SIZE - 1))
min_y = int(max(int(y) - PROXIMITY_RANGE, 0))
max_y = int(min(int(y) + PROXIMITY_RANGE, IMAGE_SIZE - 1))

total = 0
for c_x in np.arange(min_x, max_x+1):
    for c_y in np.arange(min_y, max_y+1):
        distance = math.sqrt((x - c_x)**2 + (y - c_y)**2)
        total += input[c_y][c_x] / (1 + distance)
```

Comment: Can you give a minimum example of input and output?

Comment: Currently the distance will always be zero because you override 'x' and 'y' when you use them for your loop

Comment: @JaredLovin fixed

Answer (score 0):

We can vectorize your code to be more efficient by removing the two for loops and replace them with numpy operations and slicing. Additionally, removing the standard python `math.sqrt` and replacing it with `np.sqrt` should give a performance boost, more particularly noticeable with larger matrices

```
import numpy as np

IMAGE_SIZE = 100
input = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE))

PROXIMITY_RANGE = 1
x = 5.2
y = 5.5
min_x = int(max(int(x) - PROXIMITY_RANGE, 0))
max_x = int(min(int(x) + PROXIMITY_RANGE, IMAGE_SIZE - 1))
min_y = int(max(int(y) - PROXIMITY_RANGE, 0))
max_y = int(min(int(y) + PROXIMITY_RANGE, IMAGE_SIZE - 1))

size_y = max_y+1-min_y
size_x = max_x+1-min_x

#shape x and y to be like what you had in your for loops
y_vals = np.repeat(np.reshape(np.arange(min_y, max_y+1), (-1, size_y)), size_y, axis=0).transpose()
x_vals = np.tile(np.arange(min_x, max_x+1), (size_x, 1))

#extract the bits of the input we watn 
sliced_input = input[min_y:max_y+1, min_x:max_x+1]

# compute euclidean distance
distance = np.sqrt((x_vals - x)**2 + (y_vals - y)**2) + 1

#sum the total of the cell values
total = np.sum(sliced_input / distance)

print(total)
```

Also, you had a bug where distance would always be zero. This was due to overriding `x` and `y` in your for loop iterator.